# How to send data from a container within a Pod, to a container within a separate Pod - within the same cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have a React frontend and a node.js backend. Each are in separate containers within separate Pods within the same cluster in k8's.
I want to send data between them without having to use IP addresses. I know Kubernetes has a feature that lets you talk between pods inside the same cluster, and i think its related to the selector label defined within the Service files created.

I have created a ClusterIp service for my React app and another ClusterIp for my server. I have created an ingress file for my application. I know my ingress works as i can access my UI, and i can hit my health check endpoint of my server - so i know they are exposed to the outside world correctly. My problem is how to communicate internally within k8's

Within the my react app i have tried to write 
 axios.post("/api/test", {
      value: "TestValue"
    });
But the endpoint within my server of api/test never gets hit with this.

```
Backend Server Cluster IP - - - -           

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: server-model-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: server-model
  ports:
    - port: 8050
      targetPort: 8050
```

React UI Cluster IP - - - -  

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: react-ui-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: react-ui
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000`

Ingress File - - - - -

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: react-ui-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 8050
          - path: /server/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: server-model-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 8050
```

I understand the Label selector is what maps my React Cluster IP to the Deployment for my UI and similar for my Server Cluster IP to my Deployment for server. I thin i am right in saying i can use the selector somehow to send axis/http requests to other pods like..

axios.post("/PODNAME/api/test", {
      value: "TestValue"
    });

Could anyone tell me if i am completely wrong or missing something obvious please :)

Answer (score 0):

Here in this part of ingress service name `react-ui-cluster-ip-service` is there which is running on port `3000` as you mention in service spec file.

But in you are you are sending traffic to proper service name but the port is wrong one.

```
   - path: /api/?(.*)
                backend:
                  serviceName: react-ui-cluster-ip-service
                  servicePort: 8050
```

I think due to this you are not able to send request to `/api/?`

From your service spec file you can also remove `type:clusterIP` and you can use an only service name to resolve the services inside kubernetes cluster.

answer for your question title: containers with pod can talk on `localhost` while container within separtate pod can talk over the service name there no need add the service type as `clusterIP` & `Nodeport`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Harsh, i changed the Port within my Ingress for the react-ui-cluster-ip-service to be 3000, a typo on my part. 
However, within my React UI i have this line with still doesn't work

axios.post("server-model-cluster-ip-service/api/test", { value: "TestValue" });

I am sending data from my UI to the backend server, but the server never gets it.

Can you see anything else i may be missing?

Comment: why you have added rewirte $1 ? there and i donot think you can send request like that. path you have set with service is `/server/?(.*)` wile `api/test` is in service of react.

Answer (score 0):

I have few concerns here.

As @Harsh Manvar mentioned in his answer, Kubernetes represents mechanism of discovering internal [services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) which guarantees intercommunication between Pods within the same cluster either by IP address or relevant [DNS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services) name of service.Therefore you might be able to reach your backend server from particular frontend Pod without involving [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/), as Ingress controller stays as an edge router and exposes HTTP and HTTPS network traffic from outside the cluster to the corresponded Kubernetes services.

You also used **rewrite expression** enclosed to your specific path based routing rules within Ingress object. In that scenario the rewrite seems to be resulted in the following way: `server-model-cluster-ip-service/api/test` rewrites to `server-model-cluster-ip-service/test` URI and this should be final path placeholder for you backend service. In fact that you are invoking `axios.post("server-model-cluster-ip-service/api/test", { value: "TestValue" })` request from React UI Pod might not hit the target backend service.

I just gave some points to consider how to proceed with further [troubleshooting](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-application/), at least you can log into the frontend Pod and check the connectivity to the target backend service accordingly.